# coinmarketcap issue trying to specify more than one currency

Tags: c#, json, api

The coinmarketcap API has an endpoint https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest

that accepts convert_id or convert parameters in the querystring, however, if you specify more than 1 currency id or more than 1 currency code, I get a 400 error.  As per the documentation, you should be able to specify more than 1.  For example "USD,BTC" for convert parameter (or "2781,1" for a convert_id parameter) will return `(400) Bad Request` but specifying "USD" (or "2781") works fine.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
 public static string GetHttpDataJSONStr(string URL, Dictionary<string, string> Params, MethodType Method, string API_KeyName, string API_KeyValue)
    {
        string retval = string.Empty;
        var values = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        if (Params != null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> Param in Params)
            {
                values.Add(Param.Key, Param.Value);
            }
        }
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                client.Headers.Add(API_KeyName, API_KeyValue);
                client.Headers.Add("Accepts", "application/json");
                if (Method == MethodType.GET)
                {
                    UriBuilder bldr = new UriBuilder(URL);
                    if (values.Count > 0)
                    {
                        bldr.Query = ToQueryString(values);
                    }
                    retval = client.DownloadString(bldr.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    byte[] bytes = client.UploadValues(URL, "POST", values);
                    retval = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                retval = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

and this works for all other parameters (comma delimited), such as the id parameter (for specifying multiple coins/tokens in a CSV string), so I believe my code is working fine. (NOTE: Using GET method).
I believe this may be a bug on their end (or their documentation is incorrect that you can specify more than 1 quote), but can't be too sure (and there's no place to report bugs on their API website).
Here is the exact URI sent to them:

```
https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?id=1%2c1027%2c825%2c1839%2c3635%2c512%2c3957%2c3408%2c1321%2c74%2c3897%2c291%2c4705%2c2092&convert=BTC%2cUSD%2cAUS
```

If I use `https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?id=1%2c1027%2c825%2c1839%2c3635%2c512%2c3957%2c3408%2c1321%2c74%2c3897%2c291%2c4705%2c2092&convert=BTC` ,it works fine (NOTE: I removed the other 2 currencies).

The documentation is here: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyQuotesLatest
and these calls are supported for all API account types as far as I can tell.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [CoinMarketCap API Plans](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/features), with free subscription you can use `convert` option for 1 currency per call only. Check out the error description you are getting back, you should see something like `error_message: "Your plan is limited to 1 convert options"`.

Comment: Makes sense now (yes, it's a free account, developing an app for their API, so didn't want to pay just yet)